# Deactivate a checkbox when selecting another one with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to deactivate a checkbox when I select another checkbox and activate it again when I unselect the other checkbox.

I have made this snippet:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#inputManholeStrDist1').click(function(){
            $("#inputManhole_LC_Dist").prop("disabled", !this.checked);

        }); 
    });
```

But it works in reverse. When I initially click the checkbox nothing happens and when I unclick it then the other checkbox gets disabled. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: its not a radio button.

Comment: @dkar: no, it's not; but you're replicating the functionality of a radio `<input>` using check-boxes for some reason, and breaking with conventional user-interface expectations potentially confusing your users. Why?

Comment: @ David Thomas: how can you make the conclusion from the code I pasted that I use a radio button? Which line actually indicates that?

Comment: Simple: you're changing the state of one checkbox when something happens to another checkbox. You should NEVER do that with checkboxes, it is against every design guideline.

Comment: Interesting. Is it related with security issues? A simple google search gives me lots of topics on this matter: "deactivate a checkbox when other is checked"

Comment: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/

Comment: You see the first comment:  "A Radio Button is a group of yes/no items where only one yes vote is allowed". Obviously from my code you can not make the assumption if I need a radio button or a check box. I need to have checkboxes cause I need to select multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse your condition as you want the disabled state to be same as your checkbox's checked state

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputManholeStrDist1').change(function () {
        $("#inputManhole_LC_Dist").prop("disabled", this.checked);
    }).change();//to set the initial state
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="inputManholeStrDist1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="inputManhole_LC_Dist" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#inputManholeStrDist1").click(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#inputManhole_LC_Dist").attr("disabled","disabled");
     }else{
       $("#inputManhole_LC_Dist").removeAttr("disabled");
     }
  });
});
```